# How to write a dissoc-in command for clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking to write a function that is similar to assoc-in but removes keys instead of adding it:

```
(dissoc-in {:a {:b 0}} [:a :b])
;;=> {:a {}}
```

I got up to here:

```
(def m {:a {:b {:c 1}}})

(assoc  m :a (assoc (:a m) :b (dissoc (:b (:a m)) :c)))
;;=> {:a {:b {}}}
```

but the whole nested thing is messing with my head

Comment: See http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1063 "There is no clojure.core/dissoc-in although there is an assoc-in." created in September 2012.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about:

```
(defn dissoc-in
  "Dissociates an entry from a nested associative structure returning a new
  nested structure. keys is a sequence of keys. Any empty maps that result
  will not be present in the new structure."
  [m [k & ks :as keys]]
  (if ks
    (if-let [nextmap (get m k)]
      (let [newmap (dissoc-in nextmap ks)]
        (if (seq newmap)
          (assoc m k newmap)
          (dissoc m k)))
      m)
    (dissoc m k)))
```

Example:

```
(dissoc-in {:a {:b 0 :c 1}} [:a :b])
```

Result:

```
{:a {:c 1}}
```

`dissoc-in` was once part of [`clojure.contrib.core`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure-contrib/branch-master/core-api.html#clojure.contrib.core/dissoc-in), and is now part of [`core.incubator`](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator/blob/4f31a7e176fcf4cc2be65589be113fc082243f5b/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/incubator.clj#L63-L75).

---

If you want to keep empty maps, you can alter the code slightly:

```
(defn dissoc-in
  [m [k & ks :as keys]]
  (if ks
    (if-let [nextmap (get m k)]
      (let [newmap (dissoc-in nextmap ks)]
        (assoc m k newmap))
      m)
    (dissoc m k)))
```

Example:

```
(dissoc-in {:a {:b {:c 0}}} [:a :b])
```

Result:

```
{:a {}}
```

Comment: Indeed, people have their own preferences whether empty maps should be removed or not, this is being discussed. In my use cases so far, I have chosen the original clojure.contrib.core code (quoted by Dominic above) which removes empty maps).

Comment: Docs are at:  https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator   Current lein coords are [org.clojure/core.incubator "0.1.3"].  In your require use something like " [clojure.core.incubator       :as cci]", then in program:  (cci/dissoc-in {:a {:aa 1} :b {:bb 2}} [:a :aa])  yields {:b {:bb 2}}

Comment: @0dB I just had a bug caused by removing empty maps. One of the maps was a priority map, not a regular map, so you can imagine what happened when I tried to use it later. (-> some-map (dissoc-in [:prio-map 123]) (assoc-in [:prio-map 234] something))

Answer (score 125):

I write this using **update-in**:

```
(update-in {:a {:b 0 :c 1}} [:a] dissoc :b)
```

=>

```
{:a {:c 1}}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Note that a special case is needed for a path-length of one.
```
(defn dissoc-in
  "Return nested hash with path removed"
  [m ks]
  (let [path (butlast ks)
        node (last ks)]
    (if (empty? path) (dissoc m node) (update-in m path dissoc node))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general solution based on update-in:

```
(defn dissoc-in [m p]
  (if (get-in m p) 
    (update-in m
               (take (dec (count p)) p)
               dissoc (last p))
    m))
```

Comment: Could use `(drop-last p)` instead of `(take...)`. (Or `butlast`, but that may be discouraged.)

Answer (score 4):

Being inspired by Dominic's code. I wrote a more succinct version

```
(defn dissoc-in
  [m [k & ks]]
  (if-not ks
    (dissoc m k)
    (assoc m k (dissoc-in (m k) ks))))

(dissoc-in {:a {:b {:c 1}}} [:a :b :c])  ;; => {:a {:b {}}}
```

Another version dissoc-in2 recursively removes empty maps

```
(defn dissoc-in2
  [m [k & ks]]
  (if-not ks
    (dissoc m k)
    (let [nm (dissoc-in2 (m k) ks)]
      (cond (empty? nm) (dissoc m k)
            :else (assoc m k nm)))))


(ut/dissoc-in {:a {:b {:c 3}}} [:a :b :c]) 
;;; => {:a {:b {}}}

(ut/dissoc-in2 {:a {:b {:c 3}}} [:a :b :c]) 
;;=> {}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to write one, [clojure.core.incubator](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator) already has a `dissoc-in`:

```
=> (dissoc-in {:children [{:name "Billy" :age 5}]} [:children 0 :age])
{:children [{:name "Billy"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `dissoc-in` from the [medley library](https://weavejester.github.io/medley).

Here is the code as of version 0.7.0:

```
(defn dissoc-in
  "Dissociate a value in a nested assocative structure, identified by a sequence
  of keys. Any collections left empty by the operation will be dissociated from
  their containing structures."
  [m ks]
  (if-let [[k & ks] (seq ks)]
    (if (seq ks)
      (let [v (dissoc-in (get m k) ks)]
        (if (empty? v)
          (dissoc m k)
          (assoc m k v)))
      (dissoc m k))
    m))
```

Here's a [link to the source code of dissoc-in in medley master](https://github.com/weavejester/medley/blob/master/src/medley/core.cljc).

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn dissoc-in [m ks]
  (let [parent-path (butlast ks)
        leaf-key (last ks)]
    (if (= (count ks) 1)
      (dissoc m leaf-key)
      (update-in m parent-path dissoc leaf-key))))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.